# angularJS unable to redirect to hashed route from login page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes

This is my first time using angularJS and I have a navbar where I can head to login page or click home to return to my homepage . In my homepage I have a products list and in the same  navbar I also  have a link that when I click on it scrolls down to the products . The problem is that since I use angularJS routing to redirect from home to login if I am on login page and click on products I am not redirected to my homepage and scrolled down to the products section but I stay on same page .

My code :

script.js

```
const app = angular.module("myApp" , ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(($routeProvider)=>{
  $routeProvider
    .when("/" , {templateUrl:"main.php"})
    .when("/login" , {templateUrl : "login.php"})
    .when("/register" , {templateUrl : "register.php"});
});

app
.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
  function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.gotoProducts = function() {
      // set the location.hash to the id of
      // the element you wish to scroll to.
      $location.hash('category');

      // call $anchorScroll()
      $anchorScroll();
    };
  }]);
```

The link to scroll to products a `<li>` element inside a navbar :

```
 <li class="nav__item" ng-controller = "navController">
    <!-- removed scroll link , nav link still goes -->
    <a ng-click = "gotoProducts()" class="nav__link scroll-link" >Categories</a>
 </li>
```

Aside from this problem routing works perfectly . I would appreciate your help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking redirecting to the homepage. If you just add a # you will send the browser to that hash in the current page. You can do it as easy as this

```
 $location.url('/#category');
```